# How to sort an array inside a document in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my express app, I have a preference model where users can save their preferences. It has the following structure

```
{
  _id: ...
  user: ...
  article: [{documentId: ..., addedAt: ...}]
  vlogs: [{documentId: ..., addedAt: ...}]
}
```

In brief, a user will have a single record (document) in `preference` model that will contain all the `vlogs` and `article` that user has added. Each `Article`/`Vlog` is an array of objects with a `documentId` and an `addedAt` field which holds the date when the article/vlog was added to the user's preference.

When I query this model to fetch a user's preferred vlogs and articles, I have to populate the documentId and then send only and array of populated article/vlog, which I have already done. The problem that I have is with sorting the documents by their `addedAt` date. How may I do so?

Comment: Have you tried [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with a custom compare function?

Comment: @Joe, Yes I thought of implementing it. But I wanted a way to do it with mongoose itself rather than using a JS function. If I am not wrong, for this to work I have to first fetch the populated document and then convert it into POJO, then use this Array.sort which I think is not going to be not that efficient. So, I wanted to keep it as my last resort and figure out if there is someway I can specify to mongoose itself that I wanted to sort the array at query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aggregation pipelining.

[Aggregation | MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)